# converting hex string in ipv6 format in postgresql

Tags: postgresql, ipv6

I have a hex string like `\xfc80000000000000ea508bfff217b628` in bytea format and I want to convert it into `fc80:0000:0000:0000:ea50:8bff:f217:b628` in select query, I tried:

```
select '0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0'::inet + encode(ip::bytea,'hex') from a;
```

but following error is coming

```
ERROR:  operator does not exist: inet + text
LINE 1: select '0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0'::inet + encode(stationipv6::bytea,'...
                                       ^
HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

Comment: What is the data type of the hex string? You query shows you casting it to `bytea`, but is it actually already a `bytea`, or `text`, or...?

Comment: data type is bytea

Comment: I hope that is not an address you are actually using. It is in a range reserved to be administered by a global authority that has yet to be named. If you are simply using it as an example, there is a range for that: `2001:db8::/32`, or if you want to use ULA addressing, you can locally administer in the `fd00::/8` range, but there are restrictions. For example, the next 40 bits after the `fd` must be randomly chosen.

Comment: @RonMaupin..I am suing this address just for example...just a random value..

Comment: You should use the range set aside for that: `2001:db8::/32`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`substring()` works with `bytea` values and you can use that to extract the individual parts of the bytes to convert it to an `inet`:

```
select concat_ws(':', 
                 encode(substring(stationipv6,  1, 2), 'hex'), 
                 encode(substring(stationipv6,  3, 2), 'hex'), 
                 encode(substring(stationipv6,  5, 2), 'hex'), 
                 encode(substring(stationipv6,  7, 2), 'hex'),
                 encode(substring(stationipv6,  9, 2), 'hex'), 
                 encode(substring(stationipv6, 11, 2), 'hex'), 
                 encode(substring(stationipv6, 13, 2), 'hex'), 
                 encode(substring(stationipv6, 15, 2), 'hex')
                 )::inet
from your_table
```

works on `bytea` columns

Comment: one more doubt if i have consecutive leading 0s ...it is removing it and showing fc80::ea50:8bff:f217:b628 instead of fc80:0000:0000:0000:ea50:8bff:f217:b628